# Rails Production Single JS File Isn't Precompiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-404, production-environment

So I have a file **jquery.tmpl.min.js** sitting under app/assets/javascripts/ and for whatever reason it's not being found in my production server. After runnings `rake assets:precompile` it completes without any errors whatsoever. All my other javascript assets get compiled properly and sent to the browser. I don't have any issues on my development server finding this JS file.

I have the following lines in my production.rb file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
```

Error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.tmpl.min.js"):
```

**Edit**
According to this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3596

Using the `javascript_include_tag` with something like `'jquery.ba-url.min'` wont append the .js extension. Originally I had that but have since changed it to include the .js extension. Still no dice however.

**Edit 2**
I tried adding `//= require jquery.tmpl.min.js` to my application.js but now when I attempt to precompile my assets it says it can't find the file.

**Edit 3**
Tried adding `//= require_tree` and still it isn't found. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. It turns out **Edit 2** was the fix that I was looking for. Problem was that I made the edit on development and commited to my production server using github. However I forgot to add the renamed file to the commit so all my commit ended up doing was deleting the file on the production server.